# Get cross domain API data server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, server-side

I have an API form an external source. I would like to get the API data on the server side and  load the data in a database. I never accessed an API from on the server side.
What is the best way to load the API data on the server side, can you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.